# How to programmatically configure the tunability of model parameters?

Tags: matlab, parameters, simulink

I'm porting a large Simulink model from Simulink R2010a → R2017b.

The main model is basically a glue-layer for many interwoven [reference models](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/simulink/model-reference.html). My objective is to generate a standalone executable out of this main model using [Coder](https://nl.mathworks.com/products/simulink-coder.html).

Parameter tunability in this context is **not** done via the <kbd>Signals and Parameters</kbd> section on the <kbd>Optimization</kbd> tab in the <kbd>Model Configuration Parameters</kbd> dialog (as is the case in stand-alone models), but rather, via constructing `Simulink.Parameter` objects in the base workspace, and referencing those in the respective referenced models, or in their respective model workspaces.

Now, AFAIK, in R2010a it was enough to set

```
new_parameter.RTWInfo.StorageClass       = 'Auto';
new_parameter.RTWInfo.CustomStorageClass = 'Define';
```

to make the parameter non-tunable and convert it into a `#define` in the generated code. In R2017b, this is no longer allowed; the `StorageClass` *must* be `'Custom'` if you set a non-empty `CustomStorageClass`:

```
new_parameter.CoderInfo.StorageClass       = 'Custom'; % <- can't be 'Auto'
new_parameter.CoderInfo.CustomStorageClass = 'Define';
```

But apparently, this does not make the parameter non-tunable:

> Warning: Parameter 'OutPortSampleTime' of '[...]/Rate Transition1' is non-tunable but refers to tunable variables (Simulation_compiletimeConstant (base workspace))

I can't find anything in the R2017b documentation on making parameters non-tunable, programatically; I can only find how to do it in stand-alone models via the dialog, but that's not what I want here.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

*NOTE*: Back in the day, Simulink *Coder* was called *Real-Time Workshop* (well, Real-time Workshop split into Coder and several other things), hence the difference `RTWInfo` vs. `CoderInfo`. Note that `RTWInfo` still works in R2017b, but issues a warning and gets converted into `Coderinfo` automatically.

Answer (score 0):

In generated code it should appear as #define, the way you specified it.

https://www.mathworks.com/help/rtw/ug/choose-a-built-in-storage-class-for-controlling-data-representation-in-the-generated-code.html
Btw, yes, it's a bit confusing, because in m-file you specify CustomStorageClass = '*Define*';, in GUI you specify Storage class as *Define (custom)*, but in documentation they say Storage Class as Defined.

I am not sure why warning about tunability shows up.